# Flutter bottomSheet causing error on dragging

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    bottomSheet: BottomSheet(
      onClosing: () => print("not getting called"),
      builder: (_) => Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Error (on dragging down):**

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
flutter: #1      _BottomSheetState._dismissUnderway (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:145:59)
flutter: #2      _BottomSheetState._handleDragUpdate (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:149:9)
...
```

I know I can use `showBottomSheet()` function and it works fine, but I just wanted to know why `BottomSheet` widget isn't working as expected.

Comment: Per the official code for `BottomSheet` class, its mentioned that `Bottomsheet` itself is rarely used directly. Instead, prefer to use `showBottomSheet` or  `showModalBottomSheet`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html

Comment: @DK15 I totally understand that, and I know both of them `showBottomSheet` and `showModalBottomSheet`, I just wanted to know the cause of error.

Comment: Because you don't define a controller (that BottomSheet accepts as a parameter), so it's not able to "handleDragUpdate"

Comment: @JulienLachal There is nothing like `PersistentBottomSheetController` which a `BottomSheet` accepts. What `controller` are you talking about.

Comment: I'm talking [about this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet/animationController.html)

Comment: @JulienLachal Did you try that on your own?